# Custom selection on NSOutlineView and NSCell (NSTextFieldCell)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nscell

Hello developers around the world :)
Today I have a question about the NSOutlineView customisation, the environment is:
-OS X 10.7+
- an Outline view with subclassed NSTextFieldCell

the problem: I want customise the colour end the gradient for the cell selection, my first approach was override the method

```
-(NSColor *)highlightColorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
```

in the NSTextFieldCell subclass, but the result is this:

[image]

The gradient selection still remain blu and the label background become to the returned colour. How to change the entire cell selection colour (with the gradient?)

---

UPDATE:

After subclassing the NSOutlineView and override the method:

```
- (void)highlightSelectionInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
    {
        NSRange        aVisibleRowIndexes  = [self rowsInRect:clipRect];
        NSIndexSet *    aSelectedRowIndexes = [self selectedRowIndexes];
        NSUInteger aRow = aVisibleRowIndexes.location;
        NSUInteger anEndRow = aRow + aVisibleRowIndexes.length;

        NSColor *aColor = MW_MENU_SELECTED_CELL_GB;

        [aColor set];

        // draw highlight for the visible, selected rows
        for (aRow; aRow < anEndRow; aRow++)
        {
            if([aSelectedRowIndexes containsIndex:aRow])
            {
                NSRect aRowRect = NSInsetRect([self rectOfRow:aRow], 2, 1);
                NSRectFill(aRowRect);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have the right behaviour, but without gradient, how to add the gradient (or a background image to the cell?)

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck overriding `highlightSelectionInClipRect:`.  Instead I overrode `drawRow:clipRect:`.  Something like this:

```
- (void)drawRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex clipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
{
    if ([self isRowSelected: rowIndex])
    {
        [self fillWithHighlightColor: [self rectOfRow: rowIndex]];
    }
    [super drawRow: rowIndex clipRect: clipRect];
}
```

where `fillWithHighlightColor:` is my own code.